# Using the Wrap Character in the Flat File Schema

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have to send a Flat File with each text field with the wrap character "". I have requirement that if the field has no data there should not be any "" in it. But when I make the wrap Character for a field, by default there is "" in the output irrespective of  there is data or empty. How can I handle this.

I am getting output as

"ABC", "","ABC,DEF","ABC@org.com"

"UVW","XYZ","UVW,XYZ",""

But I want it to be

"ABC",,"ABC,DEF","ABC@org.com"

"UVW","XYZ","UVW,XYZ",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create a custom pipeline component to replace the empty "" by a simple empty.

this an artcile explaining how to do it : http://boutalebhicham.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/developing-biztalk-custom-pipeline-component/

Comment: I went through the article but I am having some doubt.Why is the Pipeline used in the Receive location.Just this has to be changed "var msg = ("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + this.getStreamAsString(inmsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream())).Replace("1234","35")" to                                             var msg =this.getStreamAsString(inmsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream())).Replace("""","")

Comment: in this example, the inbound message was lost the begining xml tag, so i added the xml tag to the new message, if your message not lose this tag, you can ignore  "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"

Comment: I have used the below code but I am still getting "" in the output. var msg =  this.getStreamAsString(inmsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream()).Replace("\"\"", "");

Comment: I did a sample console application with this code:  
string a="\"UVW\",\"XYZ\",\"UVW,XYZ\",\"\"";
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.WriteLine(a.Replace("\"\"",""));
            Console.Read();


in output i get : "UVW","XYZ","UVW,XYZ",